# Listing INSERTs that cause no duplicates by avoiding single SELECTs for all entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I insert products into a `table` using `INSERT INTO DBXY.table (category, title, description, cost, supplier) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` using a prepared statement.

`supplier` is a number.

The table can already have entries that have the same category, title, description, cost and supplier. I want to know, which entries will be inserted ie those that are no duplicates. I could do a

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (category = PHPcat) AND (title = PHPtitle) AND....
```

for each entry and if the number of resulting lines is greater than 0 then we have a duplicate and no new entry. But I think this approach is flawed for 6000 and more entries. Is there are way to do this at once so I get an output that contains all new entries without inserting them just now?

Comment: Not sure if this can be done in your case, but I would put a unique index on all those keys combined.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is to define a unique index on the table (this is equivalent to a constraint):

```
create unique index table_allcols on table(category, title, description, cost, supplier);
```

You can also do this in the `insert` as well:

```
INSERT INTO DBXY.table (category, title, description, cost, supplier)
    select category, title, description, cost, supplier
    from (select ? as category,? as title, ? as description, ? as cost, ? as supplier) t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table t2
                      where t2.category = table.category and
                            t2.title = table.title and
                            t2.description = table.description and
                            t2.cost = table.cost and
                            t2.supplier = table.supplier
                     );
```

EDIT:

To just find the list of matches, create a temporary table and join between them:

```
select tt.*
from temporary_table tt
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.category = tt.category and
                        t2.title = tt.title and
                        t2.description = tt.description and
                        t2.cost = tt.cost and
                        t2.supplier = tt.supplier
                 );
```

Comment: I get `#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes` for `create unique index table_allcols on table(category, title, description, cost, supplier);`

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength . . . It does pose a problem if the fields are too long for an index.  You might still want to create the index without the offending column (which I assume is description).

Comment: Regarding the 2nd, I don't want to INSERT just yet, first I want to find out which entries would be added.

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength . . . In that case, store them in a temporary table and join between the tables.

Comment: Re: The index. I have category: varchar(2048), title: varchar(2048), description: varchar(2048), cost: varchar(12), supplier: int(11)

Comment: Re 2nd: Can you include that into your reply?

Comment: So you recommend creating a new table `tt` manually, inserting all entries using `INSERT INTO DBXY.tt (category, title, description, cost, supplier) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` and then running your command?

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength . . . Yes.

Comment: As I wrote, I need to understand how to use your command. You seem to require knowledge to use your example that I don't have. So fill the gap please.

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength . . . I'm not sure what I can add.  You need to create a temporary table with everything you want to add.  Then you can use the query to find out which ones will really be added.